# Swagger-ui is now showing api details

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, restful-architecture

I created maven webapp. All the Api's are working fine. I integrated swagger-ui and hit htp://localhost:8080/RestfulWebServiceJsonAndXml/swagger-ui.html, which shows swagger-ui [swagger-ui-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPyJ.png) but not the Api's. It is just empty. here is my github project link : [github-project](https://github.com/jugalsahu10/RestfulWebServiceJsonAndXml)

Comment: Check the browser console - are there any errors?

Comment: Browser is not showing any errors. I have even attached snapshot of swagger-ui.

Comment: Just advice: you can change `@Controller` on `@RestContoller`, and after this you don't need paste `@ResponseBody` on each method.